# JavaScript doesn't work in ajax response file aka chat.php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I can't add any working JavaScript features in the chat.php. Basically I made a instant private messaging system with AJAX and JavaScript but the thing that sucks is that the chat.php show new messages constantly which is a good thing but prevents any JS to be executed that I put in chat.php.

chat.php works with php html css etc.. but not JS. Keep in mind that I removed the JS that I wanted to put in chat.php.

The posted code below works as it is design to do like show instant messaging but again if I add any JS features for example like something simple like document.write it doesn't work it seems like.

chat.php show it for a second or it just doesn't show any JS being executed I added. So what can be the problem? I just want to add working JS features in chat.php. The JS works in the index.php area not targeted to chat.php. But targeting to chat.php it gives the same results.

**index.php**

```
<?php
include("0/instructions/php/session.php");
$session = $_POST['set_session'];
$session = $_SESSION['set_session'];
$messenger_id = $user_id;
$partner_id= $_POST['partner_id'];


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chat System in PHP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all"/>
<script>
function ajax() {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;

}
}
req.open('GET','chat.php',true);
req.send();

}
setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="ajax();">
<div class="main_container">
<div id="container">
<div id="chat_box">
<div id="chat"></div>
</div>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="conversation_id" placeholder="conversation_id"  value="<?php echo $session; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="member_name" placeholder="member_name" value="<?php echo $user_first_name;?> <?php echo $user_last_name;?>"/>
</div>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="enter message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$conversation_id = $_POST['conversation_id'];
$member_name= $_POST['member_name'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

$query = "INSERT INTO messages_x1 (conversation_id,member_name,message) values ('$conversation_id','$member_name','$message')";

$run = $connect->query($query);

if($run) {
echo "<div id='hide_audio'><embed loop='false' src='chat.mp3' hidden='true' autoplay='true'/></div>";
}

}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
include("0/instructions/php/session.php");

$session = $_SESSION['set_session'];

$query= "SELECT * FROM messages_x1 WHERE conversation_id='$session' ORDER BY message_id DESC";
$run = $connect->query($query);

while($row = $run->fetch_array()) :
$messenger_id = $row['messenger_id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.close_button {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
left: 8px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
  cursor:pointer;
bottom: 3px;
color: white;
background-color: transparent;
width: 30px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.close_button p{
position: relative;
top: -15px;
}

.close_button:hover {
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chat_data">
<span style="color:green;"><?php echo $row['member_name']; ?></span> :
<span style="color:brown;"> <?php echo  "<a class='close_button' href=\"delete.php?message_id=$row[message_id]\"onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">&times;</a>";?><br><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>

</div>
<body>
</html>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpBMW.jpg)

Comment: So, you've posted code that works, and asking about why it doesn't work when you do something to it? Did you load jquery before trying to use jquery? because you don't have any reference to the jquery library in your code in the question

Comment: I said either jQuery or JavaScript doesn't work It doesn't even work with document.write.

Comment: is there an example of this `code that doesn't work` ... because, you're probably doing it wrong, but we can't tell what you want to do from the code you posted. Also, `document.write` should never, ever be used, since the 1990's

Comment: No i'm doing it right. The ajax response file aka chat.php  just doesn't work with any js at all. I got this code from from a pro I notice he most likely made the mistake because as soon as I tried to add any JS to his code I got glitches back or no response of js but ajax does work tho.

Comment: oh, are you adding JS code to chat.php! yeah, that won't work without some extra fiddling

Comment: I'm starting to notice that so what would be the solution? I already search on google for a long time but still no solutions . I want to keep the ability to see new messages coming in at the same time I want to add any JavaScript features to chat.php .

Comment: here's some code that has worked in the past for me https://pastebin.com/EMMAHSMM ... instead of `document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;` you would `loadHtml(req.responseText, document.getElementById('chat'), true);`

Comment: I put loadHtml(req.responseText, instead of document.getElementById('chat'), true); and the chat section went away.

Comment: well, maybe the code needs tweaking :p any errors in the browser developer console?

Comment: I found out why I just remove setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000); in the index.php file by the head tag and I added some jQuery the .hide command just for a test and in the past when I put Js or jQuery commands nothing showed up or if something did show JS wise it will show for a second and the JS will disappear but when I remove setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000); every thing work JS wise but now I have lost the ability to see new coming messages now I have to load the page to see new changes. So any solutions which I can keep both? And your code didn't work the chat.php went away again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't respond with a full blown html page to an AJAX request. Just return a snippet to insert. All the CSS and JavaScript should reside in the index.php and be called as needed. If you do need to pass JavaScript from your AJAX reply, you'll have to `eval` it to be executed.

Usually nowadays only JSON data is returned to AJAX calls. Depending on how complex your JavaScript actions are this might actually make it easier to handle for you.

Comment: `you'll have to eval it to be executed` - not really

Comment: I found out the problem is setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000); and I can see why the guy who I copy put that the setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds). according to w3schools so what other solutions is there because I realize my JS was working now but it will execute the JS super fast to be able to get new messages showing up. That's why I thought my JS was working but it was it just that command made that chat.php reload super fast to get new messages.