# How can I add a setInterval to another page with AJAX and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created a private message system which consist of two files. The index.php is based on sending a private message and the chat.php file is designed on seeing the new messages appear originally I had this written in AJAX with JavaScript but I decided to convert this into AJAX with jQuery so I need to know how to add a setinterval to the whole file call chat.php, with jQuery so I can see updated messages how I use to be able to do with the JavaScript version I created originally. Here is a screen shot and the files.

[image]

**index.php**

```
<?php
include("0/instructions/php/session.php");
$session = $_POST['set_session'];
$session = $_SESSION['set_session'];
$messenger_id = $user_id;
$partner_id= $_POST['partner_id'];


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#chat").load("chat.php");
    });
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chat System in PHP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all"/>
</head>
<body onload="ajax();">
<div class="main_container">
<div id="container">
<div id="chat_box">
<div id="chat"></div>
</div>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="conversation_id" placeholder="conversation_id"  value="<?php echo $session; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="member_name" placeholder="member_name" value="<?php echo $user_first_name;?> <?php echo $user_last_name;?>"/>
</div>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="enter message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$conversation_id = $_POST['conversation_id'];
$member_name= $_POST['member_name'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

$query = "INSERT INTO messages_x1 (conversation_id,member_name,message) values ('$conversation_id','$member_name','$message')";

$run = $connect->query($query);

if($run) {
echo "<div id='hide_audio'><embed loop='false' src='chat.mp3' hidden='true' autoplay='true'/></div>";
}

}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
    include("0/instructions/php/session.php");

    $session = $_SESSION['set_session'];

    $query= "SELECT * FROM messages_x1 WHERE conversation_id='$session' ORDER BY message_id DESC";
    $run = $connect->query($query);

    while($row = $run->fetch_array()) :
    $messenger_id = $row['messenger_id'];
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .close_button {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
    left: 8px;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
      cursor:pointer;
    bottom: 3px;
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .close_button p{
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    }

    .close_button:hover {
      color: red;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chat_data">
    <span style="color:green;"><?php echo $row['member_name']; ?></span> :
    <span style="color:brown;"> <?php echo  "<a class='close_button' href=\"delete.php?message_id=$row[message_id]\"onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">&times;</a>";?><br><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>

    </div>
    <body>
    </html>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope this is just for learning purpose.
this is a classic SQL injection vulnerability.

Just use it as regular js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
 $.post({url:"...."});
}, 3000);
});
```

for more info:
[jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Thanks Shaytj but how can I make it reference to a div id call chat?

Comment: Could you explain further what you're trying to accomplish? I _think_ you're trying to do some polling but the question is not clear enough.

Comment: Basically I have two pages that makes up my private messaging system index.php is designed to use a form to send a message and chat.php is designed to see new messages. Originally this was written in JavaScript with no jQuery so I realized why not replace the JavaScript with jQuery so when I did that I lost the ability to see new messages coming in and now I have to reload the page to see new messages. The command that made that happen was setInterval but I don't know how to put it to use in jQuery and since shaytj was unclear I am confused on how to do this now would he for got to mention

Comment: the chat div meaning that's where the ajax contents will be at its located in the index.php file above.

Comment: To give you a hint what I mean in this post I was complaining a post ago that JavaScript can't be executed in my web app that's why i'm switching to jQuery because it makes it look more simpler and more stuff works easily so here's the link how it looked and work and the state that allow me to see messages commining in keep your eye on setinterval in the index.php file heres the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972985/javascript-doesnt-work-in-ajax-response-file-aka-chat-php